# How can I call another HTML page from another html page in google appscript

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script

I have created two pages in my project named as "Input.html" and "output.html" wherein on click submit button in input.html, the output will print in output.html

however I do not have idea that how can I call another page from one page

code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Input')
      .evaluate().setTitle("GL StyleGuide").setFaviconUrl("https://fonts.ab24dp.png");
}
```

Have a text area in Input page and a submit button on click of which I want my output to print on output.html page.
Modified : Sample html for Input.html is as follows

```
<div>
  <label id="label">Please Enter CSS</label>
      <textarea id="input-textarea"></textarea>
      
      <?var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?v=form'><input type='button' id="submit" name='button' onclick="addRow()" value='Get Style Guide'></a>      
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the sample script of `Input.html`?

Comment: Yes can you provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and some context? What are you trying to do? Redirect someone to "output.html" once they submit a form? Can't you just modify the HTML in place?

Comment: @Tanaike modified my question

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Comment: @kanupriya does the answer below not answer your question? I am still confused exactly what you are trying to do. Are you trying to print with printer or on screen for example?

Answer (score 1):

So one approach which I am using in one of my web apps is that I have a
`<div id = "app"></div>` in my page where I want to load another HTML.

Then I have this function to evaluate the view in my
code.gs

```
function loadPartialHTML_(params) {
  var htmlSrv = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(params);
  var html = htmlSrv.evaluate().getContent();
  return html;
}
```

Then in my main Html, I have this function which takes myView Html and populates it in defined div.

```
function loadView(options){ //loadView Function to Access Server side functions with options being an object of Parameter


var id = typeof options.id === "undefined" ? "app" : options.id; //checking if Id of Element is undefined then "app" will be used else parameter passed

var cb = typeof options.callback === "undefined" ? function(){} : options.callback; //if undefined then a blank function else function called

google.script.run.withFailureHandler(function (e){
    displayToast("errorNotification",e.message);
    loadingEnd();
}).withSuccessHandler(function(html){ //accessing server side function which will be supplied in object with "func:" which will return HTML

document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = html; //this is a call back funtion which gets html from server side and setting defined element to that return

typeof options.params === "undefined" ? cb() : cb(options.params); //if parameters were not supplied thn callback funtion with parameters else with parameters
})[options.func]();
}
```

myView HTML would be an HTML file only with elements, no header, body, etc.

You can use an event handler to load the view after the event happens.
Also, this is not my work I have learned this from a great Youtube channel here the link  for this strategy in case you got stuck somewhere : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zFowiTNhqI&t=1476s